# How to interact only two screens using websocket io

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am new in websocket IO.

I use Websocket IO in node js and laravel. I implemented instant chat using websocket. using this URL who all can use this URL and chat instantly.

But I need only two users chatting preference.

Kindly give your ideas.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to **re-organize** your questions and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Best you have send the user id or room id in url params. room id means, for example in your case there are two users.

In room table format

```
id .  room_id .   user_id
1     200         user_1
2     200         user_2
```

In your laravel route file web.php

```
Route::get('chat/{room_id}','HomeController@chat');
Route::get('chat/200','HomeController@chat');
```

In your view file

```
<script src="{{ url("assets/scripts/sjquery-3.2.1.min.js") }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url("assets/scripts/socket.io.js") }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //current url room_id
    var room_id="{{ $room_id }}";
    var socket=io.connect(LISTEN_URL);
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#submit-chat").click(function(){
            if($("#text-chat").val()!="")
            {
                //you will pass current room id in socket emit
                var data={room_id:room_id,name:$("#text-name").val(),message:$("#text-chat").val()}
                socket.emit('sendChatToServer', data);
                $("#text-chat").val("");
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Please enter text to chat');
            }
            return false;
        })
        socket.on('sendChatToClient', function(message) {
            //every time and every page and every users this socket listens, but message only enters if your current room_id and receiving data room id same
            if(room_id==message.room_id)
            {
                 $(".chat-content ul").append('<li><strong>'+message.name+'</strong> - '+message.message+'</li>');
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```